# Xcode - Game Center - accepted Multiplayer Invitation not Processing

Tags: ios, xcode, game-center, multiplayer, invitation

I am currently working on Game Center Multiplayer and have run into a few road blocks. Currently the code i have bellow will authenticate he user show the matchmaker view and start a match just fine. However when i try to invite a friend for a match the alert view asking to play the match shows when i accept it brings me to the matchmaking view controller and says it is waiting for the other player on my other device it also says it is waiting for the other player to respond. Eventually after an amount of time it says the invitation was canceled. I am not using the simulator i have 2 devices both with separate game center profiles. One is IOS 4.2 and the other is IOS 4.3. I have no idea what could be wrong. All of my multiplayer code is bellow. Also for sending data to either devices i would love to know a good site to learn more on that. Im excited to see what you all can come up with.
Thanks

ViewController.h

```
 #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
 #import <GameKit/GameKit.h>

@protocol GCHelperDelegate 
- (void)matchStarted;
- (void)matchEnded;
- (void)match:(GKMatch *)match didReceiveData:(NSData *)data fromPlayer:(NSString *)playerID;
- (void)inviteReceived;
@end

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <GKMatchmakerViewControllerDelegate, GKMatchDelegate, GCHelperDelegate, GameCenterManagerDelegate> {
 BOOL gameCenterAvailable;
BOOL userAuthenticated;

UIViewController *presentingViewController;
GKMatch *match;
BOOL matchStarted;
id <GCHelperDelegate> delegate;
NSMutableDictionary *playersDict;
GKInvite *pendingInvite;
NSArray *pendingPlayersToInvite;

}

@property (assign, readonly) BOOL gameCenterAvailable;
@property (retain) GKMatch *match;
@property (assign) id <GCHelperDelegate> delegate;
@property (retain) NSMutableDictionary *playersDict;
@property (retain) GKInvite *pendingInvite;
@property (retain) NSArray *pendingPlayersToInvite;

- (void)authenticateLocalUser;
- (void)findMatchWithMinPlayers:(int)minPlayers maxPlayers:(int)maxPlayers viewController:(UIViewController *)viewController delegate:(id<GCHelperDelegate>)theDelegate;

@end
```

and the view controller.m

```
 //ViewController.m Multyplayer


#pragma mark Initialization

- (BOOL)isGameCenterAvailable {
// check for presence of GKLocalPlayer API
Class gcClass = (NSClassFromString(@"GKLocalPlayer"));

// check if the device is running iOS 4.1 or later
NSString *reqSysVer = @"4.1";
NSString *currSysVer = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];
BOOL osVersionSupported = ([currSysVer compare:reqSysVer 
                                       options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending);

return (gcClass && osVersionSupported);
}

- (id)init {
if ((self = [super init])) {
    gameCenterAvailable = [self isGameCenterAvailable];
    if (gameCenterAvailable) {
        NSNotificationCenter *nc = 
        [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
        [nc addObserver:self 
               selector:@selector(authenticationChanged) 
                   name:GKPlayerAuthenticationDidChangeNotificationName 
                 object:nil];
    }
}
return self;
}

#pragma mark Internal functions

- (void)authenticationChanged {    


if ([GKLocalPlayer localPlayer].isAuthenticated && !userAuthenticated) {
    NSLog(@"Authentication changed: player authenticated.");
    userAuthenticated = TRUE;  

    [GKMatchmaker sharedMatchmaker].inviteHandler = ^(GKInvite *acceptedInvite, NSArray *playersToInvite) {

        NSLog(@"Received invite");
        self.pendingInvite = acceptedInvite;
        self.pendingPlayersToInvite = playersToInvite;
        [delegate inviteReceived];

    };

} else if (![GKLocalPlayer localPlayer].isAuthenticated && userAuthenticated) {
    NSLog(@"Authentication changed: player not authenticated");
    userAuthenticated = FALSE;
}

    }

- (void)lookupPlayers {

NSLog(@"Looking up %d players...", match.playerIDs.count);
[GKPlayer loadPlayersForIdentifiers:match.playerIDs withCompletionHandler:^(NSArray *players, NSError *error) {

    if (error != nil) {
        NSLog(@"Error retrieving player info: %@", error.localizedDescription);
        matchStarted = NO;
        [delegate matchEnded];
    } else {

        // Populate players dict
        self.playersDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:players.count];
        for (GKPlayer *player in players) {
            NSLog(@"Found player: %@", player.alias);
            [playersDict setObject:player forKey:player.playerID];
        }

        // Notify delegate match can begin
        matchStarted = YES;
        [delegate matchStarted];

    }
}];

}

#pragma mark User functions

- (void)authenticateLocalUser { 

if (!gameCenterAvailable) return;

NSLog(@"Authenticating local user...");
if ([GKLocalPlayer localPlayer].authenticated == NO) {     
    [[GKLocalPlayer localPlayer] authenticateWithCompletionHandler:nil];        
} else {
    NSLog(@"Already authenticated!");
}
}


- (void)findMatchWithMinPlayers:(int)minPlayers maxPlayers:(int)maxPlayers viewController:(UIViewController *)viewController delegate:(id<GCHelperDelegate>)theDelegate {

if (!gameCenterAvailable) return;

matchStarted = NO;
self.match = nil;
self.presentingViewController = viewController;
delegate = theDelegate;

if (pendingInvite != nil) {

    GKMatchmakerViewController *mmvc = [[[GKMatchmakerViewController alloc] initWithInvite:pendingInvite] autorelease];
    mmvc.matchmakerDelegate = self;
    [self presentModalViewController:mmvc animated:YES];

    self.pendingInvite = nil;
    self.pendingPlayersToInvite = nil;

} else {

    GKMatchRequest *request = [[[GKMatchRequest alloc] init] autorelease]; 
    request.minPlayers = minPlayers;     
    request.maxPlayers = maxPlayers;
    request.playersToInvite = pendingPlayersToInvite;

    GKMatchmakerViewController *mmvc = [[[GKMatchmakerViewController alloc] initWithMatchRequest:request] autorelease];    
    mmvc.matchmakerDelegate = self;

    [self presentModalViewController:mmvc animated:YES];

    self.pendingInvite = nil;
    self.pendingPlayersToInvite = nil;

}
}           

#pragma mark GKMatchmakerViewControllerDelegate

// The user has cancelled matchmaking
- (void)matchmakerViewControllerWasCancelled:(GKMatchmakerViewController *)viewController {
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

// Matchmaking has failed with an error
- (void)matchmakerViewController:(GKMatchmakerViewController *)viewController didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
NSLog(@"Error finding match: %@", error.localizedDescription);    
}

// A peer-to-peer match has been found, the game should start
- (void)matchmakerViewController:(GKMatchmakerViewController *)viewController didFindMatch:(GKMatch *)theMatch {
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
self.match = theMatch;
match.delegate = self;
if (!matchStarted && match.expectedPlayerCount == 0) {
    NSLog(@"Ready to start match!");
    [self lookupPlayers];
}
}

#pragma mark GKMatchDelegate

// The match received data sent from the player.
- (void)match:(GKMatch *)theMatch didReceiveData:(NSData *)data fromPlayer:(NSString *)playerID {

if (match != theMatch) return;

[delegate match:theMatch didReceiveData:data fromPlayer:playerID];
}

// The player state changed (eg. connected or disconnected)
- (void)match:(GKMatch *)theMatch player:(NSString *)playerID didChangeState:(GKPlayerConnectionState)state {

if (match != theMatch) return;

switch (state) {
    case GKPlayerStateConnected: 
        // handle a new player connection.
        NSLog(@"Player connected!");

        if (!matchStarted && theMatch.expectedPlayerCount == 0) {
            NSLog(@"Ready to start match!");
            [self lookupPlayers];
        }

        break; 
    case GKPlayerStateDisconnected:
        // a player just disconnected. 
        NSLog(@"Player disconnected!");
        matchStarted = NO;
        [delegate matchEnded];
        break;
}                 

}

// The match was unable to connect with the player due to an error.
- (void)match:(GKMatch *)theMatch connectionWithPlayerFailed:(NSString *)playerID withError:(NSError *)error {

if (match != theMatch) return;

NSLog(@"Failed to connect to player with error: %@", error.localizedDescription);
matchStarted = NO;
[delegate matchEnded];
}

// The match was unable to be established with any players due to an error.
- (void)match:(GKMatch *)theMatch didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {

if (match != theMatch) return;

NSLog(@"Match failed with error: %@", error.localizedDescription);
matchStarted = NO;
[delegate matchEnded];
}
-(IBAction)findMatch{
   // if (![GameCenterManager isGameCenterAvailable]) return;

matchStarted = NO;
self.match = nil;

GKMatchRequest *request = [[[GKMatchRequest alloc] init] autorelease]; 
request.minPlayers = 2;     
request.maxPlayers = 2;

GKMatchmakerViewController *mmvc = 
[[[GKMatchmakerViewController alloc] initWithMatchRequest:request] autorelease];    
mmvc.matchmakerDelegate = self;

[self presentModalViewController:mmvc animated:YES];
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle


- (void)viewDidLoad{

self.currentLeaderBoard = kLeaderboardID;

if ([GameCenterManager isGameCenterAvailable]) {

    self.gameCenterManager = [[[GameCenterManager alloc] init] autorelease];
    [self.gameCenterManager setDelegate:self];
    [self.gameCenterManager authenticateLocalUser];

    [GKMatchmaker sharedMatchmaker].inviteHandler = ^(GKInvite *acceptedInvite, NSArray *playersToInvite) {
        // Insert application-specific code here to clean up any games in progress.
        if (acceptedInvite)
        {
            GKMatchmakerViewController *mmvc = [[[GKMatchmakerViewController alloc] initWithInvite:acceptedInvite] autorelease];
            mmvc.matchmakerDelegate = self;
            [self presentModalViewController:mmvc animated:YES];

        }
        else if (playersToInvite)
        {
            GKMatchRequest *request = [[[GKMatchRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
            request.minPlayers = 2;
            request.maxPlayers = 2;
            request.playersToInvite = playersToInvite;

            GKMatchmakerViewController *mmvc = [[[GKMatchmakerViewController alloc] initWithMatchRequest:request] autorelease];
            mmvc.matchmakerDelegate = self;
            [self presentModalViewController:mmvc animated:YES];
        }
    };

}else {

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Game Center Disabled"message:@"For Game Center make sure you have an account and you have a proper device connection."delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does the NSLog: invite received gets printed in the console when you accept an invite?

[delegate inviteAccepted] method should handle what happens when a player accepts an invite.At times this can get pretty tedious since you don't know what view is currently being displayed. You should somehow find about it, push the view. Then from that view, the app should present the matchMaker viewController. My invitation block looks like this:

```
    [GKMatchmaker sharedMatchmaker].inviteHandler = ^(GKInvite *acceptedInvite, NSArray *playersToInvite){

        NSLog(@"Invite");

        if([AppDelegate mainMenuController].presentedViewController!=nil) {
            [[AppDelegate mainMenuController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^{

            }];
        }

        self.pendingInvite = acceptedInvite;
        self.pendingPlayersToInvite = playersToInvite;

        [[AppDelegate mainMenuController] presentViewController:[AppDelegate mainMenuController].multiGameMenu animated:NO completion:^{

            [[AppDelegate mainMenuController].multiGameMenu duel:nil];
        }];

    };
```

Where multiGameMenu is just a menu and the duel method just creates a game instance and calls findMatchWithMaxPlayers:int MinPlayers: int method. Let me know how it goes!!

Comment: Invite Received is printed on the NSLog.

Comment: So that means the handler actually gets called, you're just not handling it right

Comment: I have been having lots of trouble with pushing a different view for the Matchmaker ViewController i constantly get a sigbart error is there anywhere you would suggest i could maybe learn some more about pushing a view to an extra view controller? How do you do it? I am sorry I'm new to game center.

Comment: http://www.raywenderlich.com/3276/how-to-make-a-simple-multiplayer-game-with-game-center-tutorial-part-12 follow this 2 part tutorial it should help you

Answer (score 0):

Try using :

```
- (void)matchmakerViewController:(GKMatchmakerViewController *) viewController 
    didReceiveAcceptFromHostedPlayer:(NSString *)playerID
{
    [viewController setHostedPlayer:playerID connected:YES];
}
```

I hope it helps!